# Largest Datatype in GAE GO Datastore

Tags: go, types, google-cloud-datastore

What is the largest data type in google appengine go datastore. I come across a limitation in string type which is only permits 500 characters. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `[]byte`, it can store [up to 1 megabyte](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference). You can convert a string to a byte using `[]byte("Foo")` and get the string back using  `string()`.

Allowed datatypes in the datastore:

```
- signed integers (int, int8, int16, int32 and int64),
- bool,
- string,
- float32 and float64,
- any type whose underlying type is one of the above predeclared types,
- *Key,
- time.Time,
- appengine.BlobKey,
- []byte (up to 1 megabyte in length),
- slices of any of the above.
```

If you want store larger data, like big images, use the [Blobstore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/blobstore/overview) instead. Which allows data up to 32 megabytes.